# how can i deploy kibana for elasticsearch on kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-pod

could anyone help me out how to deploy kibana on Kubernetes cluster and to connect with pre-existing elasticsearch ?? I couldn't find any appropriate doc on google

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the error? You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so at least it's clear what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bare minimal to help you get started, just changed `elasticsearch` below to your own elasticsearch service name in your cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5601
  selector:
    run: kibana
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: kibana
  name: kibana
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
      value: http://elasticsearch:9200  # <-- change to your own es service url
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: kibana
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5601
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```